# Formatting Emails using Post and Request.Form.Keys C#

Tags: asp.net, post

I have a contact us form on a website and it emails to different email groups based on what a user checks at the bottom of the form. Everything works fine, but I have gotten requests to make it look nicer, but I am uncertain how to format the output when I am using Request.Form.Keys to populate the email.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    formEmail += Request.Form.Keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[i] + System.Environment.NewLine.ToString();
    ...
}
```

This is what populates the email body the code I left out is just what determines where the email goes. So my main question in this is how do I change fonts/ sizes, or is there an even better way to format it?

Thank you to anyone that can offer any advice on my question. If any additional info is needed I will do my best to add it to here.

Comment: try to use html codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get fonts and sizes in there you'll need to either add the `style` attribute to your HTML elements or add a `<style>` tag to the top of the email with the relevant CSS. Just include this markup in the string where relevant.

Comment: So if I am understanding you, you are saying it should be something like:

formemail = "<style stylehere>";
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    formEmail += Request.Form.Keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[i] + System.Environment.NewLine.ToString();
    ...
}
formemail+="</style>";

Comment: Alright, I have tried this and when the email is sent all the HTML / CSS is just put into the and not hidden as it would normally. Am I missing a key part? I even included  the html, head, and body tags to see if that would resolve my issue with no luck. Thanks for your help this far!

Comment: @JoeW, you will also need to set the format of the mail message to HTML. Set IsBodyHtml to true in the message object.

Comment: @JoeW, fantastic! I'm glad I could be of assistance.